# Creating an [authorship] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Yesterday, @verbose created a new tag [authorship](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authorship) for the question [What is the evidence that Jonathan Swift wrote "The Grand Mystery"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/26003/17) and @CDR added it to the old question [What evidence do scholars offer on both sides as to the authorship of "The Dark Tower"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/4106/17) It makes sense to have such a tag, as asking about the authorship of a work of literature is a common type of question we might see on this site. However, there are enough issues to be considered here that I thought it was worth a meta post to discuss them together:

1. **Do we want this tag?** (If anyone opposes its creation, now would be the time to say so.)
2. **What should be the definition of the tag?** (Let's write a good tag wiki and excerpt to clarify it.)
3. **Does the tag name make sense?** (Is it likely to be misused, based on its name, for other types of questions than what it's intended for?)
4. **What old questions should have this tag?** ([This search](https://literature.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22who+wrote%22+is%3Aq) would make a reasonable start.)